# The bases of Clifford algebra

Tags: clifford-algebras

In order to get the bases of Clifford algebra, I want to understand the proof of the following proposition.

**Proposition:** Let $Cl(V)$ be the Clifford algebra of a $\mathbb{R}$-vector space $V$ with inner product $\langle\cdot, \cdot\rangle$. Let $V_1$ and $V_2$ be $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces. Then, we get an isomorphism

$$Cl(V_1\oplus V_2)\cong Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes}Cl(V_2).$$

Here $\widehat{\otimes}$ is the tensor product with respect to the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded algebra.

*Proof:* We define

$$f:V_1\oplus V_2\to Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes}Cl(V_2),\ (v_1, v_2)\mapsto v_1\otimes 1 + 1\otimes v_2$$

which is a linear map between $\mathbb{R}$-vector spaces.

\begin{align*}
f(v_1,v_2)\cdot f(v_1,v_2) &=(v_1\otimes 1 + 1\otimes v_2)\widehat{\otimes}(v_1\otimes 1 + 1\otimes v_2)\\
&=(-1)^{deg(1)\cdot deg(v_2)}v_1^2\otimes 1 + (-1)^{deg(1)\cdot deg(1)}v_1\otimes v_2\\
&\quad\, +(-1)^{deg(v_2)\cdot deg(v_1)}v_1\otimes v_2 + (-1)^{deg(v_2)\cdot deg(1)}1\otimes v_2^2\\
&=-v_1^2\otimes 1 + v_1\otimes v_2 - v_1\otimes v_2 - 1\otimes v_2^2\\
&=-||(v_1, v_2)||^2\cdot (1\otimes 1)
\end{align*}

From this calculation, we induce a $\mathbb{R}$-linear map

$$F : Cl(V_1\oplus V_2)\to Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes}Cl(V_2)\ \text{ s.t. } F|_{V_1\oplus V_2} = f.$$

Finally, all we have to do is prove that $F$ is a bijection. However, I can not prove that $F$ is an injection. Please teach me.

Comment: Note that $f(v_1, v_2) \in Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes} Cl(V_2)$, so you want to compute the product $f(v_1, v_2)f(v_1,v_2)$ in that algebra, not $f(v_1,v_2)\widehat{\otimes}f(v_1, v_2)$ as you've written.

Comment: Thank you. I have proved it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see that $F$ is injective, let $\{e_1, \dots, e_m\}$ and $\{e_{m+1}, \dots, e_{m+n}\}$ be bases of $V_1$ and $V_2$, then $\{e_J \mid J\subseteq \{1, \dots, m\}\}$ and $\{e_K \mid K \subseteq\{m+1, \dots, m+n\}\}$ are bases for $Cl(V_1)$ and $Cl(V_2)$ respectively, where $e_{\{a_1,\dots,a_l\}} = e_{a_1}\dots e_{a_l}$ if $a_1 < \dots < a_l$. These give rise to a basis of $Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes}Cl(V_2)$, namely $\{e_J\otimes e_K \mid J \subseteq \{1, \dots, m\}, K \subseteq \{m+1, \dots, m+n\}\}$. Likewise, $\{e_1, \dots, e_{m+n}\}$ is a basis for $V_1\oplus V_2$, so $\{e_I \mid I \subseteq \{1, \dots, m+n\}\}$ is a basis for $Cl(V_1\oplus V_2)$.

For a fixed $I = \{i_1, \dots, i_s\} \subseteq \{i_1, \dots, i_{m+n}\}$, suppose $i_r \leq m < i_{r+1}$, then

\begin{align*}
F(e_I) &= F(e_{i_1}\dots e_{i_s})\\
&= F(e_{i_1})\dots F(e_{i_s})\\
&= f(e_{i_1})\dots f(e_{i_s})\\
&= (e_{i_1}\otimes 1)\dots(e_{i_r}\otimes 1)(1\otimes e_{i_{r+1}})\dots(1\otimes e_{i_s})\\
&= (e_{i_1}\dots e_{i_r})\otimes(e_{i_{r+1}}\dots e_{i_s})\\
&= e_J\otimes e_K
\end{align*}

where $J = \{i_1,\dots, i_r\}$ and $K = I\setminus J = \{i_{r+1}, \dots, i_s\}$. Note that if $I'$ is another subset of $\{1, \dots, m+n\}$, then $F(e_{I'}) = e_{J'}\otimes e_{K'}$ with either $J' \neq J$, $K' \neq K$, or both. Therefore $\{F(e_I) \mid I \subseteq \{1,\dots, m+n\}\}$ is a linearly independent set, so $F$ is injective.

For completeness, $F$ is also surjective. To see this, note that $F$ is an algebra homomorphism, so the image of $F$ is a subalgebra of $Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes} Cl(V_2)$. Restricting $f$ to $V_1$, we see that there is unique map $Cl(V_1) \to Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes}\{1\}$ which extends $v \mapsto v\otimes 1$. By uniqueness, it must be the map given by $c \mapsto c\otimes 1$, so the image of $F$ contains $Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes}\{1\}$; likewise, it contains $\{1\}\widehat{\otimes}Cl(V_2)$. As the image of $F$ is a subalgebra of $Cl(V_1)\widehat{\otimes} Cl(V_2)$, it follows that $F$ is surjective.

Comment: I was very impressed with the first answer I received on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

Thanks for your answer, I understand the surjectivity of F . Here, this proposition will be used in order to find the basis of Clifford algebra and its dimension. So, we have to prove this proposition without knowing them. 

By the way, if we prove this proposition and let n be the dimension of a vector space V, we can decompose Clifford algebra Cl(V) into n number of Cl(R). Therefore, since Cl(R) is isomorphic to the complex plane, we get the basis of Cl(V) and understand the dimension of Cl(V) is 2^n.

Comment: What do you mean 'this proposition will be used in order to find the basis of Clifford algebra'? Are you following some lecture notes or a book?

Comment: Please excuse my lack of explanation. Yes, I follow the Japanese book 本間泰史"スピン幾何学"(2016). First, It defines Clifford algebra and proves that if V is a one-dimensional vector space, then Cl(V) is isomorphic to the complex number field. Next it proves this proposition and decomposes Cl(V) into Clifford algebras of one-dimensional vector spaces.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by finding a basis for $Cl(V)$ using this proposition. You can write down a basis without it. That's what I've done in my answer.

Comment: Thanks for improving your answer. I realize that there is a misunderstanding between us about the meaning of the word 'basis'. The word 'basis' of a vector space V means an  linearly independent subset in V generating V. You write it the word 'bases'. Therefore, if you use 'basis'('bases') of Clifford algebra to prove this proposition, it becomes a circular reasoning.

Comment: There is no misunderstanding, I know what a basis is. Bases is the plural of basis. My point is that you can construct a basis for the Clifford algebra directly and use it to prove the proposition. If you don't want to construct a basis directly and use the proposition to construct a basis, I agree that my answer doesn't do that. Just to be clear, do you want to prove the proposition without using a basis for $Cl(V_1\oplus V_2)$? If so, I will delete my answer.

Comment: You're right, we can construct a basis for the Clifford algebra directly. I was confused by the construct of the book. The book looked as if to prove the proposition without using a basis, but It  really wants to say what you answer. Thank you so, so much.